# What does 'should' mean in this example?

Tags: modal-verbs

> Chain restaurants in Toronto **should** have calorie and sodium (salt)
> counts on their menus, according to the city’s Medical Officer of
> Health, Dr. David McKeown.
>
> According to a news release from the
> City of Toronto’s public health department, nearly half (46 per cent)
> of adults in the city are overweight. Nearly one-quarter (24 per cent)
> of adults in Toronto have high blood pressure.
>
> McKeown wants that to change.
>
> In the news release he said that, “diners
> underestimate the calories and sodium in their restaurant meals.”
> Having the calorie and sodium figures right on the menu will help
> people make healthier choices when they order their food.
>
> Many
> restaurants make nutritional information available, but it’s on a
> website or a brochure rather than right beside the food choices on the
> menu. That means people would have to look it up or ask for it from
> the server. When the information is listed right beside the menu
> items, people are more likely to consider it and use it to make better
> choices.
>
> It also lets diners compare the menu items more easily.
> Toronto Public Health **will ask** the Ministry of Health and Long-Term
> Care to develop a law that requires chain restaurants to put the
> calorie and salt counts on their menus. The change would apply to
> restaurants that have 10 or more locations in Canada, or make more
> than $10-million a year.
>
> They **will be presenting** their
> recommendations at a Board of Health meeting on April 29.
>
> ** (http://teachingkidsnews.com/)

Does the first line’s ‘should’ mean ‘should~in the future,’ corresponding to the last part: “will ask ... will be presenting”?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *should* in the first sentence is a ["deontic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality) modal, signifying that Dr. McKeown regards posting calorie and sodium counts on menus as an obligation or duty.  "Ought to" would carry the same sense.

The sentence is cast in the present tense; the 'past' form of *shall* is used when, as here, an obligation is only moral (this may be analogous to the use of past forms in hypothetical constructions). However, Dr. McKeown and Toronto Public Health want to transform it into a legal obligation. If they succeed it is not unlikely that the resulting regulation will employ the 'present' form: something like "[Restaurants] ***shall*** display the calorie and sodium content of each dish upon their menus in type of not less than XXX points in size."

Comment: I worked hard to find a definition of *should* for this case that didn't make use of *ought*.  Because I think if someone doesn't understand what *should* means they probably won't understand *ought* either.

Comment: @Jim  I think you are in many cases right. But *should* has a much greater range of uses than *ought*, and that can be confusing even for a learner who knows *ought* - does it mean *ought* here, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

McKeown is expressing his belief that restaurants have an obligation to provide the information.

> [***should***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/should) : used in auxiliary function to express obligation